# Maximum-likelihood histogram from noisy data

Tags: maximum-likelihood, algorithms, histogram, approximation, discrete-distributions

Given a sequence of noisy observations $\{x_k\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and a set of thresholds $\{t_i\in\mathbb{R}\}$ we can bin the observations using the thresholds to create a histogram.

However, since we know that the observations are noisy (e.g. additive gaussian noise of zero mean and known variance), we can use this to find a slightly different maximum-likelihood histogram, which is more repeatable than the direct histogram.

How could we accomplish this?

#### My thoughts:

I imagine the data would have an "attracting" effect on the thresholds, perturbing them so that a threshold right next to a cluster of points would move almost to the cluster's median, so that a cluster near a threshold (under the scale of the noise) ends up straddling the threshold.

#### Edit:

I feel like this could be the answer:

1. Use the noise CDFs, centered on each observation and then summed together, to construct an overall unnormalized smooth CDF, which we can call $F(x)$.
2. Lookup $F(t_i)$ and from this reverse-look-up the corresponding quantiles in the actual (piecewise constant) CDF of the data points. These are the new thresholds.

Can anyone confirm whether this is a sensible thing to do? (I am basically breaking up each observation into its PDF, allowing that to straddle bin boundaries, and then putting together unit probability masses with minimum inter-bin transfer of probability mass.)

Comment: Since you mention maximum likelihood: what kind of likelihood function you have in mind in here?

Comment: @Tim I just mean the histogram we are most likely to get if we repeat the experiment (observe the same population with noise again).

Comment: That's approximately the problem dealt with here: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1984.10478062